# SQL count problems

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a query problem with count. I want to have a column with the number of persons registered to the course.

So far, this is my query:

```
select
  courses.id, 
  name, 
  location, 
  capacity, 
  (
    SELECT count(courses_requests.IDcourse) 
    FROM courses_requests, courses
    WHERE courses_requests.IDcourse = courses.id AND status != "rejected"
  ) as Registered, 
  begin_date, 
  end_date,  
  price, 
  active
from courses
```

But this is giving me problems, it displays the same value for all rows, even if the course doesn't have persons registered in the course

E.G

```
Capacity Registered
2        1
30       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be simplier to aggregate the outer select, to eliminate the subquery, so something like:

```
SELECT      c.id, 
            c.name, 
            c.location, 
            c.capacity, 
            COUNT(cr.IDcourse) AS RequestCount 
            c.begin_date, 
            c.end_date,  
            c.price, 
            c.active

FROM        courses c

INNER JOIN  courses_requests cr
    ON      cr.IDcourse = c.id 
    AND     status != "rejected"

GROUP BY    c.id, 
            c.name, 
            c.location, 
            c.capacity, 
            c.begin_date, 
            c.end_date,  
            c.price, 
            c.active
```

Comment: Thank, this works!. Although I had to edit it a little bit. I changed the inner join to left join and an ifnull function in the count to return 0

Answer (score 0):

You should connect your subquery to main query:

```
select courses.id, 
    courses.name, 
    courses.location, 
    courses.capacity, 
    (SELECT count(courses_requests.IDcourse) 
          FROM    courses_requests, 
           WHERE courses_requests.ID = courses.id 
            and status != "rejected" ) as Registered, 
    begin_date, 
    end_date,  
    price, 
    active
    from courses
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to simplify your query ans using `SUM()` with a condition will give you the count

```
select
  c.id, 
  c.name, 
  c.location, 
  c.capacity, 
  SUM(cr.status != "rejected") as Registered, 
  c.begin_date, 
  c.end_date,  
  c.price, 
  c.active
from courses c
JOIN courses_requests cr ON (cr.IDcourse = c.id)
GROUP BY c.id
```